# Object: null prototype {} with withCredentials axios + express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I'm trying to use my cookie created by my backend, but when I make the request the `req.cookies` is: `[Object: null prototype] {}`

How I'm creating my cookie (backend):

```js
 const domain =
        process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN_TO_SHARE_COOKIES === "localhost"
            ? false
            : process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN_TO_SHARE_COOKIES;
    const secure =
        process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN_TO_SHARE_COOKIES === "localhost"
            ? false
            : true;

    res.cookie(cubikSessionCookieName, token, {
        domain,
        secure,
    });
```

How I'm making the request(front):

```js
 axios.get(`my-endpoint`, {withCredentials: true})
```

and when I use `req.cookies` in my middleware I have it as `null`.

And if **I make the request by the browser everything works as expected.. It's something between front and back, but I don't know where it is..**

Comment: I think because your cookies doesn't have httpOnly flag

Comment: You mention only a single request. Where's the other request?

Comment: @AousMohammad Hii, I added but does not work :/

Comment: @Bergi the other request it's in the browser, I just copy `my-endpoint` and put in the browser, and works

Comment: Are you saying the first request is not in the browser? Then of course it won't work since the cookies are not shared

Comment: Which one is the request where the backend does not receive the cookie in `req.cookies`?

Comment: @Bergi the first one.. the second one is on the browser

Comment: Well of course the first request does not have a cookie, it's the response to that request that sets the cookie!

Comment: @Bergi thanks, now it's making sense..

but, if the cookie is created by the backend and is accessible, why when I make the request via the frontend does it not get the cookie?

and do you get it when I just play the URL in the browser?

And then in this case, would I have to send the cookie to the frontend for it to return to the backend?

Comment: I tried with withCredentials but didn't work..

Comment: What do you mean by "*the cookie is created by the backend and is accessible*"? The cookie that is created is put in the response. The cookie that you access is part of a (different) request. You haven't shown enough code to tell where exactly you use this though.

Comment: And what do you mean by "*make the request via the frontend*"? Is your frontend not in the browser?